# React выдает ошибку при запуске "Unknown script "undefined". Perhaps you need to update react-scripts?"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, npm

Удаление **node-modules** и **package-lock.json** не помогло
Версия скриптов максимальная

При запуске возникает ошибка:

> **"Unknown script "undefined". Perhaps you need to update react-scripts?"**

Файл **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-music-player": "^1.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Пытался запустить командами **npm start** и **npm run start**

Comment: Какой командой запускаете реакт приложение?

Comment: npm start, пробовал npm run start еще

Comment: Попробуйте заменить строку `"start": "react-scripts",` на `"start": "react-scripts start",`

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло.

Answer (score 0):

В файле **package.json**, в секции **scripts** необходимо скорректировать команду для запуска

Поправить строку

```
"start": "react-scripts",
```

на

```
"start": "react-scripts start",
```

Теперь можно запускать команду `npm run start`